# No of tiles increment, with increment in size of tiles in puzzle game

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage

I have been developing a game for iPhone. Before starting the game, I read numerous article pointing to same issues(game). I found the article
[Building slide image game](http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2011/03/17/cocos2d-game-tutorial-%E2%80%93-building-a-slide-image-game-part-2-with-solution/) really a great one to start with. I incorporate the images and other associated codes fr my game.

My aim is to start with a basic image tile which will have 7 tile of images of a single one, once the user completes it in time, complexities increases with growing of tiles of other images, however when I try to decreases the tiles to minimum number, it crashes the app. I am not able to understand the effects here.

Below is where I am changing the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
for (int j = 6; j >= 0; j--) {
CCSpriteFrame *imgFrame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:texture rect:CGRectMake(i*40, j*40, 40, 40) offset:CGPointZero];
[imgFrames addObject:imgFrame];
}
}
```

I am fairly new to gamedevelopment and cocos2D.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial and it helps me resolving my issue...Really a great one.

http://www.iossdktutorials.com/slider-puzzle-ios-game-tutorial-1/

Comment: with the above tutorial one can go with 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 and 5x5 tiles.